# Product of a variety with a rational variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two algebraic varieties such that $X$ is rational 
and $X\times Y$ is unirational, do this implies that $Y$ is unirational as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The nice thing about unirationality is that it has a characterisation that is apparently weaker than the definition:

> **Proposition:** A variety $X$ is unirational if and only if there exists a dominant rational map $\mathbf P^N \dashrightarrow X$ for some $N$.

(The usual definition of unirational demands that there exist a *finite* dominant rational map as above, but given any dominant rational map as above, we can cut by appropriate hyperplanes in $\mathbf P^N$ to achieve that.)

Now suppose you have a dominant rational map $\mathbf P^N \dashrightarrow X \times Y$; composing it with the projection you get a dominant rational map

$$\mathbf P^N \dashrightarrow X \times Y \rightarrow Y$$
as required. Notice, by the way, that we didn't need to assume anything about $X$.